# Constant definitions in YII, studying 'Web Application Development with Yii and PHP'

Tags: yii, constants

Studying 'Web Application Development with Yii and PHP'. This book defines constants and Uses it in an array to provide a drop-down list.

```
class Issue extends CActiveRecord{
....

const TYPE_BUG=0;
const TYPE_FEATURE=1;
const TYPE_TASK=2;
public function getTypeOptions()
{
return array(
self::TYPE_BUG=>'Bug',
self::TYPE_FEATURE=>'Feature',
self::TYPE_TASK=>'Task',
);

....
}
```

Why did not immediately assigned to a constant value?
Why using numbers?

```
class Issue extends CActiveRecord{
....

const TYPE_BUG='Bug';
const TYPE_FEATURE='Feature';
const TYPE_TASK='Task';
```

Thank you! For helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because if you save these values(in numbers) to database and then you need to change title of any type, you just change it in your code without touching the database.